# check if field is overridden

Tags: java, checkstyle

Does checkstyle has rule which checks if subclass overrides public or protected field of a parent class.

For example

```
class Ancestor {
   public static final int VALUE = 123;
}

class Descendant extends Ancestor {
   public static final int VALUE = 100; // <-- this is unwanted
}
```

I want somehow with checkstyle to forbid such situation.

Comment: You can't override fields in Java. In your example `Ancestor.VALUE` is distinct from `Descendant.VALUE`. One does not override the other. Any references to them are determined at compile time.

Comment: @SteveKuo, that is why I want to forbid it. One can accidentally create such field, and that could lead to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Override semantics are not applicable for static fields**. When you access `VALUE` in `Descendant` then 100 is used as the value. You can also reference superclass's VALUE using `Ancestor.VALUE`.

Now, the best way to avoid confusion is to always access static members by qualifying it with class name like `Ancestor.VALUE` and `Descendant.VALUE`. The IDE's (like eclipse) let you enforce this rule but didn't see this in any of static code analysis tools. Below is the screenshot on how to enforce this in eclipse

[image]